# How to validate existence of parent id in child model in Rails for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Here are 2 models. `Order` takes nested attributes for `order_items`.

```
class order
  has_many order_items
  accept_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end

class order_item
  belongs_to :order
  validates :order_id, :presence => true  #this line cause spec failure. 
end
```

How to validates existence of `order_id` in `order_item` model? With nested_attributes, the existence of `order_id` in `order_item` is enforced already. However when saving an `order_item` on its own (not along with `order`), we still need to validate the `order_id`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you show us the create/new call that causes your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right you have trouble saving associated records with your setup:

```
params = {number: 'order-123', order_items_attributes:{product_id:1, quantity: 2, price: 3}}
Order.create params # => this should not work
```

To fix it, you need to tell Rails explicitly about associations, using `inverse_of` option:

```
class Order
  # without inverse_of option validation on OrderItem
  # is run before this association is created
  has_many :order_items, inverse_of: :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```

It's not required in your case but your can add `inverse_of` in `OrderItem` as well:

```
class OrderItem
   belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_items
   # ... the rest
end
```

More about using `inverse_of` option with associations can be read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
validates :order_id, :presence => true
```

will only make sure that some value for `order_id` was submitted. You want this:

```
validates :order, :presence => true
```

That will make sure that an `order` with the submitted `order_id` exists.

Comment: This still doesn't allow for correct validations to take place on the association. On a create action, the order doesn't have an id, and therefore the order_item doesn't have an 'order' to validate.